# Using real time data (traffic) for network analyst in ArcGIS for Server?

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcgis-server, network-analyst, real-time, traffic

I have a problem with using traffic data for routing. I'll describe the scenario:

There is a local traffic service (real time) that has the speed of each segment in the network. This information is converted to a graphic and displayed on a map. I want to use the information in network analyst. For example the user wants to route between point *x* and point *y* using one-way, time and traffic restrictions. I want to use these graphics in network analyst such that the results of routing not include the segments that have high traffic.

How can I combine these real time data in network analyst services?

Comment: Have you checked out Exercises 10 and 11 in the [Network Analyst Tutorial](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Exercise_10_Configuring_live_traffic_on_a_network_dataset/0047000001s4000000/)?

Comment: these tutorials use offline data or realtime data from global services